# REST API not returning all tags - is there a way to return all tags even ones that are not part of published posts?

Tags: javascript, rest-api, tags

I am using the REST API to upload posts and I include tags with them.  I get existing tags and check them to ensure I am not trying to upload a duplicate tag.  However, the new posts are uploaded in draft status until I have a chance to look them over and ensure everything is good before publishing them.

The issue lies in that I tend to do batch uploads, but it seems that tags are only returned if they are part of a published post.  For instance, when I go to check all the tags from the browser via https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/tags I get 147 total, but when I make the api call to get all the tags back from javascript, I only get 139 tags back(yes, I make multiple calls to the api to concatenate the results use page and per_page as queryStrings added to the url). I have verified the 8 tags not returning are all tags that are part of draft posts that are not published yet.

Is there a way so that the api returns all the tags instead of only the tags that are published?  Effectively I want the same functionality from the API as if I went to the browser and typed it in and received a bunch of JSON data back on the screen.

Obviously I can write a try/catch block to include error handling for this specifically so it doesn't stop execution, but I would prefer if it simply returned all the tags.

UPDATE: Solved thanks to @JacobPeattie(please write an answer so I can upvote it). Need to add the query parameter `hide_empty=false` in the query string.

Comment: Have you tried the `hide_empty` argument mentioned in the document? https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/tags/#arguments (You would set this to 0).

Comment: are you using the pagination? There's no code in your question to check, and the REST API has maximum limits on how many results per page it will return

Comment: @TomJNowell I answered that question in the post - "(yes, I make multiple calls to the api to concatenate the results use page and per_page as queryStrings added to the url)."

Comment: @JacobPeattie That was it! Thank you! Please post as an answer so I can upvote it and select it.

Comment: can you post that as an answer below?